# How do i copy files from a referenced assembly's structure to the local structure

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, reference

I am building a library that has some dependancies that are not compiled (example: javascript and css files).

What i would like is to have the dependant files automatically created in or copied to the consuming project's structure when the library is **referenced** - dynamically at reference time.

Through my research i have found ways to do this with pre and post build scripts on the consuming project, but what i really want to do is this:

- In **Consumer**, Add Reference to **Library**
- Code Executes that Copies all relevant *.js and *.css files from **Library's** folder structure to **Consumer** folder structure.
- If **copy** is not acheviable, i would be ok with code executing to create the relevant files in **Consumer**.

Again, i would like to avoid pre and post build scripts if i can - at the end of the day i need the **consumer** to have in place the js and css files from the **library** so that the display and execution work without forcing the **consumer** to manually move these files.

Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: Why not embed these files as resources in the assembly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans said in his comment: just embed them as resources in the assembly.  Doing so for javascript, css, and images is pretty trivial.

1. Go to the properties on the file (js/css/images) and set it's Copy to Output action to Do Not Copy and Build Action to Embedded Resource
2. In the AssemblyInfo.cs file of your assembly project add lines such as:

   [assembly: WebResource("MyAssembly.Javascript.MyJavascript.js", "application/javascript", PerformSubstitution = false)]
3. To inject the javascript into a page (from a user control or whatever located in your assembly) add the following:

   String location = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), "MyAssembly.Javascript.MyJavascript.js");

   StringBuilder startup = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);
   startup.Append(@"");
   startup.Append("");

   Page.Header.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(startup.ToString()));

Note the PerformSubstitution parameter to the WebResource directive.  This allows you to put things like the following in your embedded CSS files:

```
.ribbonGroupLeft {
    width: 3px;
    height: 85px;
    background-image: url(<%=WebResource("MyAssembly.images.RibbonGroupLeft.png") %>);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

The URL points to an image located inside the assembly.  By setting PerformSubstitution to true .net will automatically set the URL to the correct location.

As a side note, all major control library vendors do something along the lines of the above.  Works great, as long as you remember to do step 1.

Comment: Thanks Chris/Hans - i had considered that as well, but will this allow the consumer to override the CSS/JS methods if needed?

Comment: @Marc R: There are two ways to override CSS Styling.  One is to have the consumer set the !important attribute; the other is to provide the exact same class name, just later on.  For example, your CSS should be injected first.  Theirs should come second.  JS is another ball of wax entirely.

Comment: what i ended up doing was building a base class that iterates through the embedded resources and writes them to the correct folders in the consuming project if they dont already exist - that way on first run the files get created for use, then if the consuming application needs to overwrite styles they can do so.  only issue i can see off the top of my head is that once the files are edited then updates to the library will be trickey - but i think that's just a business process issue since its an internal library.

Comment: @Marc R: Interesting approach.  I guess whoever adds the library first is probably going to be responsible for making sure the new files get checked into source control.

Comment: yes - i recommended using the method you outlined but the client specifically wanted the consumers to be able to edit the CSS and JS files so i have to build out a ton of documentation to support it.